# ¿Cómo incluir un certificado en MSXML6 usando VBA?

Tags: vba, aeat-sii

Estoy intentando conectar con AEAT para el SII pero no sé cómo poner el certificado en `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP`. ¿Admite MSXML2 algún comando, o algo para elegir el certificado? ¿Cómo incluir un certificado en MSXML6 usando VBA al consumir un web service que lo pide?

Parece que coge "UN" certificado de la carpeta personal de certificados y parece que coge el último introducido.

El wsdl de AEAT contesta con:

> A)Es necesario un certificado
>   B)El certificado no es válido (coge el mío personal en vez de el de la empresa
>   C)Parece que funciona si hay sólo un certificado o es el último introducido

¿A alguien le pasa lo mismo?

El código es:

```
Dim XML As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
...
Set XML = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP.6.0")
...
With XML
  .Open "POST", BASE_URL, False
  .send TextoMandar
End With
...
```

`BASE_URL` es la del servicio web del SII, tanto la real o la de prueba, que figuran en:
https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl

TextoMandar es un XML que se envía como texto.

Comment: ¿Has probado añadiendo `.setOption 3, "Common Name (CN) parte del nombre del certificado"`?

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo pruebo esta noche. La empresa usuaria tiene que tabrir sesión con usuarios distintos y cada uno tiene en sus carpetas pric¡vadas un solo certificado. Es un "workaround" y una chapuza, en fin...

Comment: Revisa esta forma de hacerlo: **[VBA ServerXMLHTTP https request with self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11600385/5587982)**

Comment: @FernandoCorral ¿probaste la solución que puse? Si no funciona, la borro para ver si con la recompensa alguien más se anima al ver que no tiene respuestas

Comment: En https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753798(v=vs.85).aspx pone que con la opción 3 se puede seleccionar el certificado. Ahora no encuentro la manera de elegir el certificado digital, uso certmgr.msc y veo los certificados, pero no parecen que tengan un nombre (??). Resumen: no sé como se pone el Common Name de: "Common Name (CN) parte del nombre del certificado". He visto algo de generar un CSR pero creo que va de otra cosa. En fin, estoy por abandonar y cambiar a ver si se puede hacer con WinHTTP server versión 5.1

Comment: He explorado muchos foros y he encontrado el mismo o parecido problema sin resolver. Ya es un reto, voy a mirar también la API de Iexplorer u otras y también el comando de línea CertMgr.msc. Llevará tiempo....

Comment: @FernandoCorral Abre certmgr.msc; ve al certificado que quieras usar y pulsa dos veces sobre él; de ahí pulsa en la pestaña de Detalles (details); y mira "Subject", dentro habrá varios valores y uno es CN (que coincide con el nombre que aparece en el "issued to").

Answer (score 1):

Las páginas de soporte de Microsoft tienen un artículo en español sobre el tema: [Cómo instalar el certificado de cliente en el servidor de IIS para el objeto de solicitud ServerXMLHTTP](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/301429/how-to-install-client-certificate-on-iis-server-for-serverxmlhttp-requ). En dicho artículo se describe cómo instalar un certificado en IIS, errores comunes,

Aunque en un español algo especial, sí se puede encontrar una nota sobre qué hacer cuando hay varios certificados, para seleccionar sólo uno de ellos:

> **Nota**: Si tiene varios clientes certificados están instalados, puede utilizar el método **setOptions** y el parámetro *SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT(Option 3)* con el objeto **ServerXMLHTTP** en MSXML 3.0 SP1 para especificar el nombre del certificado del cliente, como sigue:
>
> ```
> sxh.setOption(3) = "Common Name (CN) part of certificate's Subject name"
> ```
>
> Si se especifica una cadena vacía ("") se utiliza el valor, el primer certificado en el almacén (que también es el valor predeterminado).

Aplicando eso a tu código, deberías intentar hacer lo siguiente (ojo no lo he probado y puede contener fallos):

```
Dim XML As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
...
Set XML = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP.6.0")
...
With XML
  .Open "POST", BASE_URL, False
  .setOption 3, "Common Name (CN) parte del nombre del certificado"
  .send TextoMandar
End With
...
```

La cosa es que en la documentación se habla de MSXML3, pero parece que en tu código estás usando MSXML2. Por lo que no sé si eso te funcionará.

Comment: El día 1 de julio empezó el sistema SII de la Agencia Tributaria en real. Estamos muchos pillados. Hay hasta el día 12 para empezar a mandar la información. Como hay una salida muy mala, que es cargar y descargar certificados estamos así. No creo que pueda probar en unos días, aunque lo necesito. Tengo que probar también con WinHTTP. Gracias

Comment: En Identifying correct client certificate for ServerXMLHTTP.SetOption de stack overflow proponen el mismo problema. También voy a investigar por ahí en cuanto tenga tiempo, hay cosas interesantes.

Answer (score 1):

Al final tuve que usar WinHttpRequest que tiene la opción SetClientCertificate.
Se añade CAPICOM V2.1 Type Library en las referencias, que tiene el objeto "STORE" con todos los certificados y la colección "Certificates", los listas y buscas el CN (SubjetName) de cada uno, que se lo pasas a SetClientCertificate. Y encima, funciona!